# is there any suitable tflite dependecies, image picker dependencies and unicordialer depedencies for sdk version sdk: ">=2.1.0<3.0.0"?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm having problem with dependencies of flutter because I have a problem with the package tflite, image picker, and unicorndialer. Currently, I'm using tflite dependencies 1.0.3 but it cannot function properly the error say

```
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/config
Building a flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Running "flutter packages get" in emotions...
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.
```

Because emotions depends on image_picker >=0.3.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.1.4 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)

Answer (score 0):

> changed dependencies

image_picker: any

or 
you can get latest image_picker version.